In Drush, how to enable path-based language negotiation for emulated requests?
I'm building a path access checker as a Drush command. It would take Drupal's internal path (for example: /langcode/my-path) and user ID and check if the path is accessible, returning a boolean accordingly. It works as expected, except for the language. The language code is always the site's default language during the emulated request. How can I make emulated requests honor path language prefixes as it does during web requests?
\Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage()->getId();

I'd like this to return the language of the path prefix. If my path is /fr/... then I'd like this function to return the same fr.
I have tried a lot of methods to override this without success. I see that Drush has a different language negotiation than web requests. It seems it does not have path negotiation, since in Drush there are no requests.
  public function checkPathAccessForUser(
    string $path,
    int $uid
  ): bool|string {

    // Load the user entity.
    $user = User::load($uid);
    if (empty($user)) {
      return 'User not found';
    }

    //Simulate a request.
    $request = Request::create($path);

    // Create a request context to simulate the specific user access.
    // This must be done before matchRequest().
    $request_stack = \Drupal::service('request_stack');
    $request_stack->push($request);

    $route_provider = \Drupal::service('router.route_provider');

    try {
      $route_match = \Drupal::service('router.no_access_checks')->matchRequest($request);
    }
    catch (\Exception $e) {
      $message = $e->getMessage();
      return $message;
    }
    finally {
      // Pop the request stack.
      $request_stack->pop();
    }

    // Match the request to get the route name.
    $route_name = $route_match[RouteObjectInterface::ROUTE_NAME];

    // Get route parameters.
    $parameters = $route_match['_raw_variables']->all();

    // Check if the route is accessible for the given user.
    $access_result = \Drupal::service('access_manager')->checkNamedRoute($route_name, $parameters, $user);

    return $access_result;
  }


Have you come across drush-current-language? In theory I think that should be a drop-in solution

You can create Drush site aliases for languages other than the primary:
japanese:
  root: /var/www/html/web/
  uri: https://www.jaypan.com/ja

Then you can use the alias to call the language:
drush @japanese uli
